# How to make RecognizerIntent start different Activity that if was started from?

Tags: android, android-intent, recognizer-intent

In my application Activity A uses startActivityForResult to send a RecognizerIntent. Is it possible to tell it give results back to Activity B without going back through Activity A?

Comment: I was playing around with a PedingIntent but couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 0):

`PendingIntent`s are not meant to have results passed back to the caller, so that's out.

If ActivityB is behind ActivityA in the backstack, simply do this:

```
ActivityA {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        setResult(resultCode, data);
        finish();
    }
}
```

This will pass to ActivityB whatever data the `RecognizerIntent` Activity passed back to ActivityA.

If ActivityB is a separate Activity that you want to start when the `RecognizerIntent` Activity is completed:

```
ActivityA {
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
        intent.putExtras(data);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

That will start ActivityB from ActivityA, passing the data through as a bundle that can be retrieved via `getIntent().get___Extra(String key)`

Comment: thank you for taking the time, but your answer is exactly what I had in mind (and working code) when I asked "without going back through Activity A"

Answer (score 0):

Using a PendingIntent you can push the results to activity B without returning to A:

**In Activity A:**

```
Intent activityIntent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
PendingIntent resPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, activityIntent, 0);

Intent speechRecIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
speechRecIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
speechRecIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
speechRecIntent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS_PENDINGINTENT, resPendingIntent);


PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, speechRecIntent, 0);
    try {
    pendingIntent.send();
} catch (PendingIntent.CanceledException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

**Then in Activity B**, you get get the results in it's onCreate():

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
if(intent.hasExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
ArrayList<String> speechRecResults = intent.getStringArrayList(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
```

Comment: do I start it without view as startActivity or startActivityForResult?

Comment: You don't have to. You invoke the speech rec. activity by calling pendingIntent#send. I've edited my answer

Comment: Applying the pattern above to my code causes the application to crash with a "com.google.android.wearable.gmsclient.WearableException: sendRpcAsync failed: Status{statusCode=unknown status code: 4000, resolution=null}" Exception.